# If you create a password protected tournament with "Show to Your Clan" on, do clan members need the password to join?

Tags: clash-royale

Since the most recent update, Clash Royale tournaments have more configuration parameters.

If you "Set Password" for a tournament with the "Show to Your Clan" flag on, do clan members who want to join the tournament need to know and enter the password to join it?

Meaning: do I need to give them the password, or does simply closing the clan and not giving out the password allow me to "lock down" the tournament to clan members only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  If "Show to Your Clan" is flagged "on", for a password protected tournament, clan members do not require the password to join.

Having a password set, and "Show to Your Clan" on, and not distributing the password to anyone, and closing the clan to new members for the duration of the tournament effectively locks down the tournament to only your clan members.

If you only want it for specific people within your clan, set a password, set "Show to Your Clan" off, and contact the people directly with the password.

Answer (score 0):

No, they don't. However, be careful, since people might enter your Clan and force their way into the Tournament. Never let your Clan open while hosting a Tournament.